# Play framework create DEB and deploy it on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scala, ubuntu, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm using Play Framework 2.3.8 with Scala, and I'm trying to create DEB package to install it on prod server. After installation it should automatically run thru "services"

I've added to `build.sbt`:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

packageDescription := """Admin Application"""

maintainer := """Admin <contact@maintainer.com>"""
```

After executing

```
activator debian:packageBin
```

it generates deb file, but after installation script `/etc/init.d/testApplication` is not working

How can I make it working on Ubuntu 14.04?

I tried to use `Java Application Archetype` basing on http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/

I've added:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._

packageArchetype.java_application
```

But sill without success

===== Update

After setting `Upstart`, during installation I'm getting:

```
Selecting previously unselected package testApplication.
(Reading database ... 61317 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack testApplication_0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking testApplication (0.1) ...
Setting up testApplication (0.1) ...
Creating system group: testApplication
Adding group `testApplication' (GID 115) ...
Done.
Creating user testApplication in group testApplication
start: Unknown job: testApplication
testApplication could not be started. Try manually with service testApplication start
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
```

And running script manually still doesn't give any results

```
michal@cantrace:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/testApplication start
 * Starting testApplication                                  [ OK ]
michal@cantrace:~$ ps aux |grep java
michal    1807  0.0  0.0  11744   920 pts/0    S+   18:33   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Any error messages? Is the script even present?

Comment: It displays something like `* Starting deamon testApplication` and there is no java process, I'm checking by `ps aux |grep java`. Does it work for u, using debs?

Comment: Any messages in the `application.log`?

Comment: It didn't even run application, there is no application.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered similar problem on Debian.  The default configuration of the DEB package is broken.  By default the application would create a RUNNING_PID file in `/usr/share/[your application name]` on startup.  This would fail due to invalid file permission.  To fix:

- After installing the DEB package, edit `/etc/default/[your applicaiton name]` and uncomment the following line and restart the service:

  > `-Dpidfile.path=/var/run/[your application name]/play.pid`
- Or, upgrade sbt-native-packager to v1.0.0 and override the default config.

To upgrade,

1. In `[project root]/project/plugins.sbt`, add:

> `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0")`

2. In `[project root]/build.sbt`, remove the following imports:

> `//import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._`
>   `//import NativePackagerKeys._`

3. Create `[project root]/dist/conf/application.ini` and specify the new defaults:

> `# Since play uses separate pidfile we have to provide it with a proper path`
>   `-Dpidfile.path=/var/run/[your application name]/play.pid`

Hope it helps.

Comment: `-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null` is a good move since systemd is typically doing this role.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic service managers in DebianLike system.

- `Upstart` deafult for Ubuntu 14
- `SystemV` default for Debian 7

Depending on target system you should use `Upstart` or `SystemV`

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.YourServiceManager

packageArchetype.java_server

serverLoading in Debian := YourServiceManager
```

`Upstart` store it scripts in `/etc/init`

`SystemV` store it scripts in `/etc/init.d`

Here you have more info about this configuration:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/java_server/index.html#customize

Comment: When I'm trying `sudo service testApplication start` it returns `start: Unknown job`. When I try `sudo /etc/init.d/testApplication start` it shows is starting `Starting testApplication` but there is no java process

Comment: your app is located in `/usr/share/testApplication/bin/testApplication`. Please try to tun it form shell and write here what happened

Comment: it is running application on 9000 port, so there is something wrong in daemon scripts

Comment: Sorry. I make some mess here. I use `Debian` and it use `SystemV` by default. In your case - `Ubuntu` it is better to use `Upstart` which is default for this system. It is a reason why `service` command don't find a script on Ubuntu. Please switch `SystemV` to `Upstart` in your `build.sbt`. If you will still have problems attach listing `/etc/init/testApp`